# How to transfer table's data to new table?

Tags: mysql

I need to transfer the data of 2 tables into the new table, here is the simplified table.

Table 1

```
user_id_slot_1 | user_id_slot_2 | some_column | some_column_2
```

Table 2

```
user_id_slot_1 | user_id_slot_2 | some_column | some_column_2
```

**Note:**

- Data from table 1 and 2 that I need to transfer/copy is almost identical.
- `user_id_slot_1` and `user_id_slot_2` either one of them should be
  empty/null.
- Column's names are different from the actual database.

New Table

```
id | user_id | some_column | some_column_2
```

How can I transfer the data from Table 1 and 2?

How can I merged the column `user_id_slot_1` and `user_id_slot_2` into one and transfer it to `user_id`.

**UPDATE:**

I do not need to transfer/copy the ids of the Table 1 and 2, New Table needs to `auto increment` it.

Comment: So out of 4 user_ids (2 rows * 2 columns), only 1 will have a value?

Comment: yes, either slot 1 or slot 2

Comment: In what way do table 1 and table 2 differ?

Comment: Table 1 have columns that the Table 2 don't have and vice versa. The only thing that I need to transfer/copy are columns that the Table 1 and 2 have.

Comment: Your update invalidates the answers already given.  And you didn't even show us sample data for what the new table should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the new table already exists, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to move the data.  I have used `UNION ALL` here under the assumption that you don't want to remove duplicates between the two source tables should they occur.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (`user_id`, `some_column`, `some_column_2`)
SELECT COALESCE(user_id_slot_1, user_id_slot_2),
       some_column,
       some_column2
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(user_id_slot_1, user_id_slot_2),
       some_column,
       some_column2
FROM table2
```

Notes: The `COALESCE(user_id_slot_1, user_id_slot_1)` term in the above query will choose `user_id_slot_1` if it be not `NULL` otherwise it will choose `user_id_slot_2`.  This should be fine assuming that one and only one will be non `NULL` for every record.

Assuming that the `new_table` table has its `id` column set to auto increment, then MySQL will handle assigning these values for you.  All you need to do is *omit* a value for `id` in `new_table` and MySQL will handle the rest.

You should create the new table using something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    some_column VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    some_column_2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Will try this and will respond afterwards!

Comment: I received an error, `1 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized statement type. (near "ALL" at position 339)`

Comment: @DumbQuestion Then your syntax has some problem.  The query I gave you should be working assuming you replaced the column and table name appropriately.

Comment: Most likely, the problem lies in your PHP code, perhaps escaping is the culprit.

Comment: Sorry! It works, but `id` in the new table does not auto increment and not start from 1, also `user_id` has some `0` values on it

Comment: I updated my answer.  Just don't insert a value for the `id` in new table, and MySQL will auto increment it.

Comment: Thanks, It worked! Though I got a minor problem, the `user_id` has some 0 value on it and upon searching for `COALESCE` it returns the first non-NULL value, but `user_id_slot_1` and `user_id_slot_2` is `int` so if the slot is empty the default value is 0, how can I change it? so that the non-0 value will be stored in `user_id`.

Comment: Please show data regarding this.  Are you saying that you want to treat zero values as `NULL`?

Comment: I just want to get the "real" user's id in which is technically can not be 0, I get an alternative instead of `COALESCE` I used `GREATEST` so that anything greater than 0 will be stored in `user_id` which I needed, I will vote your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
create table3 as
    select id, coalesce(user_id_slot_1, user_id_slot_2) as user_id,
           some_column, some_column_2
    from table1
    union all
    select id, coalesce(user_id_slot_1, user_id_slot_2) as user_id,
           some_column, some_column_2
    from table2;
```

Comment: I am not sure if the `create` is the right thing but, I want to transfer/copy the data from the 2 tables to the new table. But will try this.

Comment: @DumbQuestion . . . You can `insert` instead, if you have already defined the table.